# WebEx meeting scheduled for another user

Tags: webex

I need to get a recurring meeting setup for someone I report to.  I need this meeting to be scheduled in his name, but I can't seem to find out how that is done... even though this is mentioned in the documentation.  How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other Person has to log in to WebEx with his host-Account and can at "**My Profile**" select in the "**Session Options**" with the Button "**Select from Host List**" your Account as a deputy for Webex.

When you are his deputy you can go to the "**Advanced Scheduler**" and select in the Dropdown-menu
Schedule for: "Name"

hope that helps.

Comment: Give me a little bit to verify and I'll mark this solved.